# uiimageview.image memory leak

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, uiimageview

In my applicayion i am using a uiimageview ,and it will load diffrent images on a button click. But there is memory leak when i load images, is that needed to release uiimageview.image property before i load another image to it. Any help please...........

code for loading images to uiimageview

```
-(void)setOverlayImage:(UIImage *)img
 {

  overlayView.image=nil;    
  overlayView.image=img;

  }
```

Before i do overlayView.image=img; i hope the memory allocated for the previous image will be replaced with the new image.
Or is that needed to do [overlayView.image release] and then overlayView.image=img;???????
But when i tried to release, the app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setOverlayImage:(UIImage *)img
 {

  overlayView.image=img;

  }
```

This should be sufficient but you can also go for this.

```
-(void)setOverlayImage:(UIImage *)img
{

  if(overlayView)
  {
    [overlayView release];
    overlayView = nil;
  }
  overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
  overlayView.frame = yourFrame;
  // Add this to your parent view
  [self.view addSubview:overlayView];
}
```

Hope this helps